# Angular Material 17 styling inactive MatTabs color

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image]

Hello, how I can modify my theme setup to make the text of inactive tabs darker?

I don't see the value of the color of those inactive tabs to be defined anywhere in the palette definition.
I don't want to modify it only for single usage of the component but for changes to be reflected on the whole theme.

this is the content of my theme.scss file atm

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

$red-palette: (
        50: #ffebee,
        100: #ffcdd2,
        200: #ef9a9a,
        300: #e57373,
        400: #ef5350,
        500: #f44336,
        600: #e53935,
        700: #d32f2f,
        800: #c62828,
        900: #b71c1c,
        A100: #ff8a80,
        A200: #ff5252,
        A400: #ff1744,
        A700: #d50000,
        contrast: (
                50: rgba(black, 0.87),
                100: rgba(black, 0.87),
                200: rgba(black, 0.87),
                300: rgba(black, 0.87),
                400: white,
                500: white,
                600: white,
                700: white,
                800: white,
                900: white,
                A100: rgba(black, 0.87),
                A200: white,
                A400: white,
                A700: white,
        )
);

$gray-palette: (
        50: #fafafa,
        100: #f5f5f5,
        200: #eeeeee,
        300: #e0e0e0,
        400: #bdbdbd,
        500: #9e9e9e,
        600: #757575,
        700: #616161,
        800: #424242,
        900: #212121,
        A100: #d5d5d5,
        A200: #aaaaaa,
        A400: #303030,
        A700: #616161,
        contrast: (
                50: rgba(black, 0.87),
                100: rgba(black, 0.87),
                200: rgba(black, 0.87),
                300: rgba(black, 0.87),
                400: rgba(black, 0.87),
                500: rgba(black, 0.87),
                600: white,
                700: white,
                800: white,
                900: white,
                A100: rgba(black, 0.87),
                A200: rgba(black, 0.87),
                A400: white,
                A700: white,
        )
);


$my-primary: mat.define-palette($red-palette);
$my-accent: mat.define-palette($gray-palette);

// The "warn" palette is optional and defaults to red if not specified.
$my-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
        color: (
                primary: $my-primary,
                accent: $my-accent,
                warn: $my-warn,
        ),
        typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
        density: 0,
));

// Emit theme-dependent styles for common features used across multiple components.
@include mat.core-theme($my-theme);

// Emit styles for MatButton based on `$my-theme`. Because the configuration
// passed to `define-light-theme` omits typography, `button-theme` will not
// emit any typography styles.
@include mat.tabs-theme($my-theme);

// Include the theme mixins for other components you use here.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you inspect the element of the label text, these are the CSS style rules applied for the inactive tab and hovered inactive tab.

```
.mat-mdc-tab .mdc-tab__text-label {
    color: var(--mat-tab-header-inactive-label-text-color);
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.mat-mdc-tab:hover .mdc-tab__text-label {
    color: var(--mat-tab-header-inactive-hover-label-text-color);
```

When you click the variables, the color used for the variables are as below:

```
.mat-mdc-tab-group, .mat-mdc-tab-nav-bar {
    --mat-tab-header-inactive-label-text-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    --mat-tab-header-inactive-focus-label-text-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    --mat-tab-header-inactive-hover-label-text-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

You can overwrite the CSS styling rule as below:

```
.mat-mdc-tab .mdc-tab__text-label {
  --mat-tab-header-inactive-label-text-color: $gray-palette.900;
  // Alternative
  // --mat-tab-header-inactive-label-text-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-accent, 900);
}

.mat-mdc-tab:hover .mdc-tab__text-label {
  --mat-tab-header-inactive-hover-label-text-color: $gray-palette.900;
  // Alternative
  // --mat-tab-header-inactive-hover-label-text-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-accent, 900);
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/haej25?file=src%2Ftheme.scss)

Comment: So these colors are not defined through the theme?

Comment: Hi, apologize for late reply, I think no as the color is predefined: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/23e2f3eeb29e39229cb56b4fd58852bd484e6da5/src/material/core/tokens/m2/mat/_tab-header.scss#L22